How do I get parent only or child only pages? PHP
I'm having some issue with a PHP code which allows to get parent only or child only pages from the menu. I want to be able to have the parent page clickable if there aren't child pages. Anyone who can help? Here's the code:
//Get parent terms only
function bdb_get_parent_terms($postid=null,$taxonomy){
  if ($postid === null)
  return false;

  $terms=wp_get_post_terms($postid,$taxonomy);
  $termr = null;

  if($terms){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->parent=='0') $termr[]=$term;
    }
    return $termr;
  }
  return false;
}

//Get parent terms only
function bdb_get_father_terms($postid=null,$taxonomy,$type){
  if ($postid === null)
  return false;

  $termsFather=wp_get_post_terms($postid,$taxonomy);

  if($termsFather){
    foreach ( $termsFather as $termFather ) {
        $termsFatherArr[]=$termsFather;
    }
    return $termsFatherArr[0][1]->$type;
  }
  return false;
}

//Get child terms only
function bdb_get_child_terms($postid=null,$taxonomy){
  if ($postid === null)
  return false;

  $terms=wp_get_post_terms($postid,$taxonomy);
  $termr = null;

  if($terms){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->parent!='0') $termr[]=$term;
    }
    return $termr;
  }
  return false;
}

// Check if has children page
function bdb_has_children($postid) {
  
  global $post;
  $pages = get_children($postid);
  
  if (!empty($pages)):
    return true;
  else:
    return false;
  endif;
}


I included postid and taxonomy for the parent page with no child page that I want to be clickable but still not working
